# How to change the port of geckodriver

Tags: selenium, geckodriver

I was getting "bind: address already in use" exception when bringing up a docker container. The docker container was trying to use port 30000  but it was reserved for geckodriver.
For some reason i need to reserve that port for that container, is there any way to change the port for geckodriver. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: i am using java